# Override Working Folder with Starteam/CruiseControl

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, starteam

For some reason, I can't seem to get CruiseControl.net to checkout code to anywhere but the starteam working folder for a specificed view.

I've tried both overrideViewWorkingDir and overrideFolderWorkingDir, and neither seem to work.

Has anyone been able to do this?

Comment: Could you post the exact configuration you are trying when using the overrideFolderWorkingDir parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the project's [workingDirectory element](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Project+Configuration+Block) instead of the [starteam override](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/StarTeam+Source+Control+Block)?

Answer (score 0):

```
<sourcecontrol type="starteam">
    <executable>C:\Program Files\starbase\StarTeam 5.4\stcmd.exe</executable>
    <project>ProjectName/ViewName</project>
    <username>UserName</username>
    <password>Password</password>
    <host>127.0.0.1</host>
    <port>49201</port>
    <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
    <overrideViewWorkingDir>C:\temp\ProjectName</overrideViewWorkingDir>
</sourcecontrol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me with ccnet 1.4.3 and Startem Cross-Platform Client 2008 R2. Make sure XML is valid. I had overrideViewWorkingDir tag not properly closed and ccnet was ignoring it. Found it by running ccnet.exe from the command line instead of as a service. Also you can use Process Explorer from SysInternals to view command line arguments passed to stcmd.exe

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your working folder properties are set to a relative and not a full path (ex:  MyFolder instead of C:\MyProject\MyFolder) or it will override the override. I've seen files checked out to some very odd places in the past when people mistakenly put in full paths when adding a folder to a view.